# Trying to figure out if there's a shorter/better way to implement a conditional-sum-like function

Tags: perl

**Warning: Project Euler Problem 1 Spoiler**

I recently discovered [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) and decided to try a few of the problems.  The first problem was to sum the numbers from 0-999 that are multiples of 3 or 5.

My first, "java-like" solution was:

```
print threeAndFive(1000)."\n";

# Returns the sum of the numbers less than $max that are multiples of 3 or 5
sub threeAndFive
{
    my $max = shift;
    my $sum = 0;

    for (my $i=; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        $sum+=$i if (validate($i)); 
    }   

    return $sum;
}

sub validate
{
    my $num = shift;

    if ($num % 3 == 0 || $num % 5 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return undef;
}
```

I then rewrote it in a more perlish fashion:

```
print eval(join ('+', map {($_ % 3 == 0 || $_ % 5 == 0) ? $_ : ()} (1 .. 999)));
```

While this is obviously way more concise than the original code, I feel that it can probably be shorter or done in a better fashion.  For example, in Python, one can do:

```
print sum([i for i in range(1,1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0])
```

Are there more concise/better/clearer ways to do this? Or other equivalent ways that use different functions?  I'm interested in learning as much perl as I can, so the more solutions, the merrier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: enjoy; as you move on, have a whack at writing your own big int stuff (the problems introduce needed functionality only a little at a time) or just use Math::BigInt/BigRat

Comment: print List::Util::reduce { $a + (($b % 3 == 0 || $b % 5 == 0) ? $b : 0) } 0,(1..999);

Comment: @MkV: um, List::Util::reduce to avoid List::Util::sum?  blech

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Straightforward Approach

To answer your question, List::Util provides `sum`.

```
use List::Util qw( sum );
```

Or you could write your own

```
sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }
```

Then you get:

```
say sum grep { $_ % 3 == 0 || $_ % 5 == 0 } 0..999;
```

Of course, that's an unoptimised approach.

---

### The Optimised Approach

You can easily reduce the above to Ω(1) memory from Ω(N) by using a counting loop.

```
my $acc;
for (1..999) { $acc += $_ if $_ % 3 == 0 || $_ % 5 == 0; }
say $acc;
```

But that's far from the best, since the result can be obtained in Ω(1) time and memory!

This is done by adding the sum of the multiples of 3 to the sum of the multiples of 5, then subtracting the sum of the multiples of 15, because the sums of the multiples of $x can be calculated using

```
( sum 1..floor($n/$x) ) * $x    # e.g. 3+6+9+... = (1+2+3+...)*3
```

which can take advantage of the formula

```
sum 1..$n = $n * ($n+1) * 0.5
```

Answer (score 5):

Less concise, but faster:

```
sub sum1toN { my $N = int(shift); ($N * ($N+1)) / 2; }
my $N = 999;
print sum1toN($N/3)*3 + sum1toN($N/5)*5 - sum1toN($N/15)*15, "\n";
```

The `sum1toN` function computes [the sum of integers from 1 to N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%8B%AF).

Since:

```
3 + 6 + 9 + 12 ... + 999
```

Equals:

```
(1 + 2 + 3 + ... 333 ) * 3
```

We can computes sum of multiples of 3 using `sum1toN(N/3) * 3`. And the same applies to 5. Note that since we count the multiples of by 15 in both cases, a subtraction of `sum1toN(N/15)*15` is needed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.